# How to get box index number using only javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to get box index number using Javascript. like i have four box so i want each box text have this appropriate number.

```
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function () {
   var Main= document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('div');

for(i=0; i<Main.length;i++){



}

  }
  </script>
  <style>
  .box {
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    position:relative
  }
  .width {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:20px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="box">

      <img src="img/sample1.jpg" height="200" width="300" />
    </div>
    <div class="box">

      <img src="img/sample2.jpg" height="200" width="350" />
    </div>
    <div class="box">

      <img src="img/sample3.jpg" height="200" width="150" />
    </div>
    <div class="box">

      <img src="img/sample4.jpg" height="200" width="100" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all your JS with this below and place the script tag as the last tag in your body tag to assure the DOM is ready when this is called.  You could also call this function from the `onload` event.

```
(function(){
    var Main= document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var i=0; i<Main.length;i++){
      Main[i].innerHTML += "box"+i;
    }
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mmjW9/

Comment: one more thing i have another div inside box div so how to sort out this. above function will not give desire result.

Comment: You should post all of your mark up up front.  It is hard to give a good answer if you don't post everything.  My answer answers your questions as it was posted.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload=function() {
   var Main= document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('div');

  for(var i=0; i<Main.length;i++){
    Main[i].innerHTML+= '<span class="title">box '+(i+1)+'</span>';
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/FH4MA/)

Comment: This isn't going to work because you need to access the array values.

Comment: Yeah, but took forever to write up in jsfiddle on my iPad so you posted a working version in the meantime :(